Graph theory: Question regarding planar graphs and Eulerian paths
Does a graph $G$ with $6$ vertices and $9$ edges exist such that:
$G$ is planar and connected.
$G$ contains an Eulerian path.
$G$ contains two non-adjacent vertices, such that connecting them with an edge will make the graph not planar.
I assume the answer is no, but I'm having trouble proving it.

Okay, sorry. Here's a corrected answer. It is possible.
Take $K_{3,3}$. Remove one one of the edge between vertices $u$ and $v$. Then add back an edge between two vertices in $V - \{u,v\}$. The resulting graph is planar, since this graph will no longer contain $K_{3,3}$ as minor. It will also have degree sequence (4,4,3,3,2,2). So it has a Eulerian tour.
Now to meet condition $(3)$ simply re-insert the edge $e_{uv}$

You can do something a little bit more elegant, but for an illustrative example you can just brute-force this.
So, by condition $(2)$ your graph can have at most two vertices of odd degree. If it has exactly 2 then it has an open Eulerian path, otherwise it has a Eulerian tour.
Since your graph $G$ has 9 edges the sum of its vertex degrees is 18 by double counting. We are thus looking at only 4 possible degree sequences: (4,4,4,4,1,1), (4,4,4,2,2,2), (4,4,3,3,2,2), and (5,5,2,2,2,2). There is also (5,5,4,4,0,0), but your graph is connected so we don't even have to check is this is an acceptable sequence (it is not).
The first one of these we can rule out, because, by Erdös-Gallai, it is not the degree sequence of any graph.
The other two are. So, for those we have to check whether they meet your other conditions.
1. Case: (5,5,2,2,2,2):
Now this graph, up to isomorphy, has a single planar realization, which I don't know how to draw here, but you can visualize two nodes $u$, $v$ which are each connected to the four other nodes as well as share an edge. You could also visualise the bipartite graph $K_{2,4}$ and add an edge between the two nodes on the left (obviously, in that case it is no longer bipartite).
We will show that this graph violates your condition $(3)$ by showing that we cannot find two vertices $v_1$, $v_2$ s.t. if we connect them we will make the graph non-planar. This would be obvious from a visualization, but we will also prove it here formally. By Kuratowski theorem we know that a graph is non-planar exactly when it contains either $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as minors. Since this graph only has 6 vertices and is not $K_{3,3}$ it does not contain it as a minor. The other possibility is for it to have $K_5$ as a minor for some way of adding an edge. But we can already see it has too few edges for that, even if you add an edge.
2. Case (4,4,4,2,2,2) and (4,4,3,3,2,2):
These graphs are outerplanar, or rather have outerplanar realizations. Hence, any new edge can be drawn as a curve with all vertices on one side. Hence, if we add any edge these graphs remains planar.

$(5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1), (5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2), (4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1)$?

missed those :|. In that case it probaly $is$ better to use a more general method of proof, perhaps via Euler's formula.

Or argue intuitively via Kuratwoski: it's clear that the graph cannot have $K_5$ as a minor even if you add an edge. As it is it has $just$ enough edges to be $K_{3,3}$. But to transform $K_{3,3}$ into a graph that has a Eulerian path you need to change at least two edges. Adding a single edge you can thus never get a graph that has $K_{3,3}$ as a minor.

My arguments are wrong: I found an example. But now I'm asking myself what was wrong with my reasoning..
